# Error with creating regex expression to match a specific URI pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, web-scraping

**DEVELOPER LEVEL -** I've recently started web development.

**PROBLEM -** 
I've been trying to create a regex expression to match the following `uri` pattern in a code.

**[https://photos.google.com/share/`...`/photo/`...`?key=`...`](https://photos.google.com/share/%60...%60/photo/%60...%60?key=%60...%60)**

For a nice example - ↓↓THIS↓↓ 
https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPFB_fAYv9UKMfQJnS_AyinAMKN_NOfumadYm-N7WAdRhAjiKgfF03ejiHs2AumgQ/photo/AF1QipNDQb-ngSW1zIz4W338p225dMXVDDReKIAZULU?key=RmhDdS1FQnZEV0pid0o4dDlTX1MwWjdVZXhkOFZn

I've been trying really hard but couldn't get it to work. This is my regex expression - 
`/\["(https:\/\/photos\.google\.com\/share\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]\*)"/g`

**PROJECT BASED -** NodeJS, express

Comment: You can use `https:\/\/photos\.google\.com\/share\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/photo\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\?key=[a-zA-Z0-9]+` https://regex101.com/r/NZO9MB/1

Comment: Works awesome!! Thanks, friend, really appreciate your help

Comment: You are welcome, the answer is already posted I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it.

```js
function extract_url() {
  var content = "Content: https:google.com - https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPFB_fAYv9UKMfQJnS_AyinAMKN_NOfumadYm-N7WAdRhAjiKgfF03ejiHs2AumgQ/photo/AF1QipNDQb-ngSW1zIz4W338p225dMXVDDReKIAZULU?key=RmhDdS1FQnZEV0pid0o4dDlTX1MwWjdVZXhkOFZn https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPFB_fAYv9UKMfQJnS_AyinAMKN_NOfumadYm-N7WAdRhAjiKgfF03ejiHs2AumgQ/photo/AF1QipNDQb-ngSW1zIz4W338p225dMXVDDReKIAZULU?key=RmhDdS1FQnZEV0pid0o4dDlTX1MwWjdVZXhkOFZn";
  var patt = /https:\/\/photos\.google\.com\/share\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/photo\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\?key=[a-zA-Z0-9]+/;
  var result = content.match(patt);
  document.getElementById("urls").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="extract_url()">Extract URL</button>
<p id="urls"></p>
```